# ¿Cuando sé que ha cambiado un ImageView?

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo un `ImageView` con una imagen, la idea es que cuando se pulse puedas elegir una imagen de la galería.

Pero necesito una comprobación de si se ha añadido una imagen o no.

He probado poniendo una variable y cambiarla en el método de cargar imagen, pero como hago intents pues no funciona esa idea.

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

**XML**

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/foto2"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />
```

**Código**

```
    if (imagenElegida.equals("foto2")) {
            Glide.with(this)
                    .load(imageUri)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .into(foto2);
            FOTO_AÑADIDA = "SI";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de seleccionar la imagen:

```
Drawable imagen_antigua = imageView.getDrawable();
```

Cuando haya seleccionado la imagen nueva invoca esta función (mediante el onclick o el método que uses):

```
if (imageView.getDrawable() == imagen_antigua)
      {

           Toast.makeText(CreateAccountActivity.this, "No has elegido una nueva imagen!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
```

En caso de que quieras hacer este proceso por si no tiene **ninguna** imagen basta con cambiar a:

```
imageView.getDrawable() == null
```

Answer (score 2):

> Pero necesito una comprobación de si se ha añadido una imagen o no.

La mejor forma de comprobar si se ha añadido es mediante:

```
 if (imageView.getDrawable() == null){
       //No existe imagen.
   }else{
        //Existe imagen.
 }
```

es importante comentar que librerías como `Glide` o `Picasso` tardan un poco en cargar la imagen en el `ImageView`, por esta razón debes esperar unos milisegundos para realizar la correcta comprobación.

```
    //Carga imagen.
    Glide.with(this)
            .load(imageUri)
            .into(imageView);

   //Espera 500 ms para verificar.
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (imageView.getDrawable() == null){
              //No existe imagen.
            }else{
              //Existe imagen.
            }
        }
    }, 500); //ejecuta despues de 500 ms
```